# Symbolic Link: Creating link from "NTFS Partiton" to ~/Desktop

Tags: partitioning, permissions, symbolic-link

I'm facing difficulty in creating a symbolic link to `/media/my-username/storage/folder` in `~/Desktop` by using:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ln -s '/media/username/Storage/My-Files/semester-5' .
```

It creates a **broken link** instead of the symbolic link. I've checked the ownership of *Storage*; it has **root** permissions, and it is an NTFS partition (because I've dual booted the with windows). I think it is *read/write permission* problem.

Any idea what should I do for that?

Comment: Change ownership of `Storage` to the user. And what is the command. Your commad doesn't create a symlink to Desktop. And is the NTFS partition permanantly mounted if fstab?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, it is permanently mounted in *fstab file*.
I've used `chown -R username:username /media/username/Storage/`, but it isn't effecting on ownership of `Storage` it is still **root permission**.

Comment: Is the partition mounted? Is the path correct? Usually in Windows it is `My Files`, not `My-Files`. Just some ideas...Be aware of case sensitivity, `storage` is not the same as `Storage`

Comment: Please check my edit, I think this is what you meant and this way it is what your command should do.

Comment: @mook765 1. Partition is mounted. 
2. Yes, the path is correct.
3. I usually do not use *space* while naming the directory. But i checked path and spellings that are same as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Do you have execute permissions on `/media/username/Storage` and all it's parent-folders?

Comment: Yes, `Storage` has `rwx` permissions but the owner is `root`.

Comment: I just tried to make `sym link` by GUI and after few clicks, it created a link directory( same as a shortcut folder in Windows) in the same directory, and I put it to `~/Desktop`. Now it works fine. But i couldn't understand why it is not creating this link via terminal using `ln` command!

Comment: @linxnerd I don't have an explanation for that mysterium other than a typo in the path when using the terminal. As long as you have execute permission for the directories you to enter to reach the target there shouldn't be a problem, a sym-link actually is a  path which points to the target, crossing file-system borders or different file-systems are no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comments, creating a symbolic link via GUI works, but it does not work via `ln`. This is because `ln` will use relative path sometimes.

For verification, you can create a symbolic link via `ln` and GUI, then you inspect the properties of this two and you will find the link target is relative path for that create by `ln` and for the other is absolute path.